# How to solve ImportError: No module named certifi

Tags: linux, debian, python, submodule

I am using Debian  Testing, and I am trying to install couple modules one them is the discog client. However I keep hitting this certifi thing which I have no iodea about.

According to my python installation, **certifi module is in the system**. See the lines below.

```
python

Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 05:55:50) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import certifi
>>> certifi.where()
'/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
```

Here is the erroring.

```
pip install discogs-client

File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.certifi import where
ImportError: No module named certifi
```

Here is pip install certifi

```
pip install certifi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.certifi import where
ImportError: No module named certifi
```

Comment: Probably `# pip install certifi`. ... https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

Comment: @KnudLarsen I wish it was that easy. I added pip install result in the original post

Comment: ?Maybe "Debian Testing" isn't quite complete yet? ..... Debian 9.3 : My certifi-install.log.txt : https://www.dropbox.com/s/c57qz7ho6ta09k7/certifi-install.log.txt?dl=0 .... Which Debian are you using ? Debian 10 Buster or Debian "11" Sid ? → → `# apt install python-certifi` https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python-certifi

Comment: `#  pip install discogs-client` → https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3od35za3c1ly6a/discogs-client-install.log.txt?dl=0

Comment: @KnudLarsen like I mention in the original post, the first command line entry is already showing that python-certifi is installed, because as you see I can import it. I am looking for indepth help here, not install this pckage and solves my issue.  As you see the issue is a bit more complex. Also it already does not install discogs module, see the original post.

Comment: OK, I will try `pip install ***` with Debian 10 Buster (testing). .... Later.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I dont think that my issue is distro issue, I can install certifi on my other Debian testing unit. Something got broken along the way, that is what I want to fix.

Comment: One common error with pip can be multiple installs of pip. Please check `/home/name/.local/` : Can contain an extra pip, if you did like `$ pip install pip`, i.e. as unprivileged user.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, no pip there, neither in my user nor in the roots

Comment: What is your `pip` version (`pip --version`)? Is it version 10? Looks to me like you've tried to upgrade `pip` via `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` recently.

Comment: @hoefling pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: Roll back to version 9: `apt-get install --reinstall python-pip` and don't update `pip` via `pip` itself.

Comment: @hoeflingit issuing that command did not solve the issue for me. See https://paste.debian.net/hidden/4ddf99d8/ What happened to Python man? This kinds of dependency issues want not a problem bacl then